# Programmatically create a comment form for a node

Tags: forms, 8

I'm trying to port a theme from Drupal 6 to Drupal 8, and I find code like the following.

```
$edit = array();
$edit['nid'] = $node->nid;
$form = drupal_get_form('comment_form', $edit));
```

How do I load the form in Drupal 8? I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getEntityTypeId() on null in /www/site/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityForm.php on line 77

The line causing the error is the following one:

```
\Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\comment\CommentForm');
```

I can't work out how to pass the node object to the form builder. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

[`FormBuilder::getForm()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormBuilder.php/function/FormBuilder%3A%3AgetForm/9.4.x) doesn't accept just a single argument; it accepts additional arguments that are passed to the functions called by `FormBuilder::getForm()`, including the unique form constructor function. These values are available to implementations of [`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/9.4.x) and [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/9.4.x) as `$form_state->getBuildInfo()['args']`.

To build an entity form, though, Drupal core uses the [entity.form_builder](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.services.yml/service/entity.form_builder/9.4.x) service instead of [form_builder](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.services.yml/service/form_builder/9.4.x). The following is the code used in [`CommentLazyBuilders::renderForm()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21comment%21src%21CommentLazyBuilders.php/function/CommentLazyBuilders%3A%3ArenderForm/9.4.x) to build the comment form.

```php
$values = [
  'entity_type' => $commented_entity_type_id,
  'entity_id' => $commented_entity_id,
  'field_name' => $field_name,
  'comment_type' => $comment_type_id,
  'pid' => NULL,
];
$comment = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('comment')
  ->create($values);

return $this->entityFormBuilder->getForm($comment);
```

[`EntityFormBuilder::getForm()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityFormBuilder.php/function/EntityFormBuilder%3A%3AgetForm/9.4.x) accepts two arguments more; the second one is the operation to be done on the entity. Passing `'delete'` as second argument, the code would obtain the form to delete the entity.

Answer (score 2):

kiamlaluno's solution didn't work for me. This did:

```
$values = array(
    'entity_type'  => 'node',
    'entity_id'    => $node->id(),
    'field_name'   => 'comment',
    'comment_type' => 'comment',
    'pid' => NULL,
);

$comment = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('comment')->create($values);
$formHTML  = \Drupal::service('entity.form_builder')->getForm($comment);
```

Answer (score 1):

Example in core using lazy builder approach to make it work properly with caching per permission

http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/core/modules/comment/src/Plugin/Field/FieldFormatter/CommentDefaultFormatter.php#n194